# Is there a way to declare a mock model in Django unit tests?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

Title says it all. I'll illustrate the question by showing what I'm trying to do.

I have extended Django's `ModelForm` class to create a `ResourceForm`, which has some functionality built into its `clean()` method for working with `Resources`, the details of which are unimportant. The `ResourceForm` is basically a library class, and there are no models in the app where the `ResourceForm` class is defined, so I can't just use an existing model from the app (e.g., `mock.Mock(spec=SomeModel)` is not an option).

I am trying to unit test `ResourceForm`, but I can't figure out the right way to mock a Django `Model`, which is required since `ResourceForm` inherits from `ModelForm`. This is one of several efforts I have tried (not using `mock` in this case, but it serves to illustrate what is being attempted):

```
class ResourceFormTestCase(TestCase):

    class SampleModel(Model):
        sample_field = CharField()

    class SampleResourceForm(ResourceForm):
        class Meta():
            model = SampleModel
            fields = ['sample_field']

    def test_unsupported_field_raise_validation_error(self):
        print('Test validation error is raised when unsupported field is provided')
        form_data = {'sample_field': 'FooBar', 'unsupported_field': 'Baz'}
        form = self.SampleResourceForm(data=form_data)
```

But that raises:

```
RuntimeError: Model class customer.tests.tests_lib_restless_ext.SampleModel doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

I'm open to suggestions if I'm way off-base in how I'm trying to test this.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing that might work is to use the [user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/) that comes with Django.

If that's not acceptable, I have successfully patched enough of the Django plumbing to make it shut up and run unit tests without a database connection. Look in the [`django_mock_queries` project](https://github.com/stphivos/django-mock-queries/blob/v0.0.16/django_mock_queries/mocks.py#L43) to see if any of that is helpful.